Why is Hibernate generating two queries instead of a join?
I have a OneToMany relationship and Hibernate generates two SELECT queries instead of making a JOIN.
I'm using the following stack (let me know if you need more information):
Blaze Persistence Core + EntityView 1.6.11
Hibernate 6.4.4 final
Spring Boot 3.2.5
I have the following entities:
@Entity
@Table(
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(name = Truth.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME, columnNames = {"slugified_name", "rules_package_id"})
        }
)
@NoArgsConstructor @Setter @Getter
public class Truth implements NonCollectableNode {
    public static final String UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = "UC_truth_name_rules_package_id";

    //other fields omitted for brevity

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "truth", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<TruthOption> options = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class TruthOption {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "truth_id", nullable = false)
    private Truth truth;

    private String summary;
    
    //other fields omitted for brevity


and the following entity views
@EntityView(Truth.class)
public interface TruthResponseView {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();

    //other methods omitted for brevity

    List<TruthOptionResponseView> getOptions();
}

@EntityView(TruthOption.class)
public interface TruthOptionResponseView {
    String getSummary();
}

This is my method in my custom repository implementation.
public Optional<TruthResponseView> findDtoById(UUID id) {
        CriteriaBuilder<Truth> criteriaBuilder = criteriaBuilderFactory
                .create(entityManager, Truth.class)
                .where("id").eq(id);
        CriteriaBuilder<TruthResponseView> truthResponseViewCriteriaBuilder = entityViewManager.applySetting(EntityViewSetting.create(TruthResponseView.class), criteriaBuilder);

        TruthResponseView truthResponseView;
        try {
            truthResponseView = truthResponseViewCriteriaBuilder.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            truthResponseView = null;
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(truthResponseView);
    }

and the generated queries I see in my console
Hibernate: select t1_0.id,t1_0.canonical_name,t1_0.color,t1_0.dice,t1_0.name,t1_0.replaces,t1_0.rules_package_id,t1_0.slugified_name,t1_0.your_character from truth t1_0 where t1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select o1_0.truth_id,o1_0.id,o1_0.summary from truth_option o1_0 where o1_0.truth_id=?

I don't really understand what is happening, because I have two other entities that follow a similar association and the query is generated as expected.
I have tried explicitely defining the join for the CriteriaBuilder but it didn't change anything.

Are you sure that the queries you are observing are created by this query? Are you maybe using a special FetchStrategy for the getOptions()?

Thanks to your comment, I poke around a bit more and it turned out my repository implementation had a typo in the class name. I thank you for getting back to me so fast!

The problem was due to a typo in the class name of my repository implementation, after correcting it, the query is the one I expected
